# long outputs in Rstudio presentations (alternative to allowframebreaks for multiple pages)

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

I am having problems with long outputs in the new Rstudio presentation format. The latter looks much more efficient than Latex+ Sweave but I miss an option that automatically adds page breaks so that the output spans multiple pages, e.g. the "allowframebreaks" for beamer slides.

I also tried knitter chunk-options but could not find a solution.

Here is a minimal Rpres file in which only a part of the output is shown.

````
example
========================================================
```{r}
rnorm(100)
```
````

Any help much appreciated.